# Percentage Height Behaving Differently on Firefox and Safari MAC

Tags: html, css, safari

i am having a weird problem here, height of li elements behave differently in firefox and safari.

**[HERE IS THE FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu6Q7/1/)**

**[Another Simple Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/RLt7c/2/)** Suggested by Mr Lister
See above demo in firefox and safari and its not working.

HTML

```
<ul class="projectlist clearfix">
<li class="project">
    <a href="#" rel="16" class="ajax">
                <img width="340" height="236" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="5" />         
        <div class="projectinfo">
            <div class="meta">
                <h4>Something</h4>
                <h6><em>asdfasdf</em></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio {
    width: 100%
}
.projectlist {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: transparent
}
.projectlist li {
    width: 25%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left
}
.projectlist a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 85px;
    position: relative
}
.projectlist a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.projectinfo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100
}
```

Firefox

[image]

Safari

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for Safari?

Comment: @AliBassam Added the screenshot.

Comment: Try to use only `width:100%;` and remove `height:100%;` from `.projectlist a img`

Comment: You have CSS errors like `a: hover`. Correcting them won't solve the issue though. Hm.

Comment: I made a thoroughly simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/RLt7c/2/) that shows the issue clearer: In a block of 200x100 pixels, Safari displays the image at 200x100 as well, while Chrome and other browsers ignore the 100% height property of the image (i.e. they honour the image's intrinsic w/h ratio rather than obeying the CSS). This feels like a bug in all the other browsers, honestly.

Comment: @AliBassam that works, of course (provided you also remove the `width` and `height` attributes from the `<img>` tag!) but it doesn't answer the question why this happens.

Comment: Hey, where is the question? What you want to achieve?

Comment: @MrLister yes very true, so there wont be any workaround for this ?, coz i am having this issue in ipad and iphone safari too, and i am making responsive theme and its not rendering well in safari.

Comment: @VikasGhodke Yes, but what is the eventual goal? I mean, the image should be 100% high, 100% of what exactly? I mean, keeping the height at `auto` works, so isn't setting only the width enough?

Comment: Like I said, Ali Bassam's solution works. But I'm still curious why you put `height:100%` in to begin with.

Comment: Oh man, dont know how i missed Ali Bassam's answer, now its working fine check here.. http://jsfiddle.net/RLt7c/3/ if you or ali bassam can make it as an answer then i can accept it. Thank you for all your help, its my mistake that i put the height 100%; but still dont knw why different browser render percentage height differently.

Comment: OK, glad to have cleared that up. But as I said, I also don't know what causes the differences. My instincts say it's a bug in every other browser but Safari. But if Chrome and Firefox and Opera and even IE agree on something, that's difficult to ignore.

Comment: I usually work with Firefox, and I use `width:100%;` on images a lot. I like it because it simply tells the picture to maintain your width at 100% and stretch your legs, the image will be resized in a good way. Safari seems to prioritize the height over the width, Safari is telling to the image to maintain the height at 100% and stretch your width, I think so :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer as from the Comments:

Use only `width:100%;` on the image and remove `height: 100%;`. 
This will tell the browser to resize the image in a way to respect the 100% of the width, or more like, fix your width then stretch your legs.

*This answer needs some improvement.*